# Azure Function at a specific time interval for each client

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions

My requirement is to run a Job at a scheduled time(for each client).

My *.net core* Application will be used by multiple clients.
Logged in user who belongs to a specific client(with admin permission), schedule this job at a particular time using UI interface and save it to DB.
So then all data related to only this client should be processed by the job on the specific date.
While another client user may schedule a different time.

For example:
Client X- job should run on 5th of every month

Client Y - job should run on 21th of every month

Client Z - job should run on 15th Jan every year

As per technical requirement, this should be addressed as an **Azure Function**.

So my challenges are:

1. How to create multiple instance of *Azure Function* for each client.
2. How to dynamically set `TimerTrigger` for each instance. (Note: when the user update the schedule, the timer should be dynamically reset.)

Else if this is implemented as `HttpTrigger`

1. How to time multiple instance and trigger it.

Thanks,

PRI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you have a database / table that includes the information of what jobs are supposed to run when? So when the user schedules a job from the UI it writes something like this to a database:

| JobID | ClientID | DateToRun | Interval | JobStatus |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 2024-03-15 | Monthly | Pending |

Then you could write one TimerTrigger function that runs every day and queries the database to see what jobs are due that day. If a job is due, it executes your function on that client's data and then updates the DateToRun field based on the interval value (I.E. Monthly = run on same day next month).

Creating a whole new function for each client is not good practice--do not do this. You should store your application state in a database, queue, or other similar tool.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Was thinking of some solution as above. But wanted to confirm whether multiple instance is possible. Will try the above and comment again...

Comment: Is a solution to this is possible with Orchestration....any views please